# Keep getting a "Classifier 'SharedViewModel' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here" error when using a view model

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting two errors in my code. One is at the private val sharedView model, I keep getting an "Classifier 'SharedViewModel' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here". Lastly, in both the lines of question.text = sharedViewmodel.question and question.text = sharedViewModel.answer I'm getting an "Type mismatch.
Required:
Editable!
Found:
String?" but when I try to change it to editable I then get an error below my button click listener for question/answer.text.toString(). Does anyone have any idea how to fix these? Here's my code:

```
    package com.example.quest

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels(SharedViewModel)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)
        val answer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)

        if(sharedViewModel.question != null) {
            question.text = sharedViewModel.question
        }

        if(sharedViewModel.answer != null) {
            answer.text = sharedViewModel.answer
        }

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener {

            sharedViewModel.question = question.text.toString()
            sharedViewModel.answer = answer.text.toString()
            val questiontext = question.text.toString()
            val answertext = answer.text.toString()

            val returnIntent = Intent()
            returnIntent.putExtra("test", questiontext)
            returnIntent.putExtra("test2", answertext)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)

            finish()
        }
    }

    }
```

Viewmodel:

```
    package com.example.quest

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var question: String ?= null
    var answer: String ?= null

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `by viewModels()` without passing the name of the class. You don't need to pass anything when your ViewModel has an empty constructor.

Instead of `question.text = sharedViewModel.question`, use `question.setText(sharedViewModel.question)`. Same thing with the other one. The problem is that there are multiple `setText()` methods for TextView defined in Java. Kotlin creates a property out of the one whose parameter type matches the return value of `getText()`, which returns an Editable instead of a String. So the property access syntax for TextView only works with Editables rather than Strings.

Answer (score 0):

`SomethingViewModel:class.java` usally a typo. Pay attention to the fullcolons and ensure they are always two, that is `SomethingViewModel::class.java`